# Error in hadoop project using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, pom.xml

I want to create a project where I want to count the frequency of occurrence of names from a file using hadoop. So, I am trying this using maven. But as soon as I put the dependencies for hadoop in pom file I get an red color error mark on project but there is nothing wrong in pom file. And, when I use the jar file  which I got from packaging the programs using maven on the data file I get the error of "exception in thread main: ClassNotFoundException" though i have point out the main class as well in pom file. But, This all setting is working fine when I am making package using command line maven.

Comment: Can you post the dependencies in error in your pom.xml ?

Comment: I added hadoop-core, hadoop-hdfs, hadoop-common, hadoop-auth and hadoop-annotations as dependencies

Comment: @KuldeepSingh, update your post with the POM dependencies and saying only `ClassNotFoundException` is not enough. Stack trace is also required to figure out missing library.